# Should I create a second WAN Interface for a new SSLVPN setup on my Sonicwall 2400?

Tags: vpn, firewall, sonicwall, wide-area-network, a-record

Sonic Wall 2400

I'm setting up a new SSLVPN on our Sonicwall, very new to this.

I currently have an exchange server as well, so mail.company.com is directed to our mail server. I'd like to setup a clean link for my low end users, remote.company.com to be for the SSLVPN, but I'm not sure how to do this within the Sonicwall?

I setup SSLVPN on port 443. Only 1 WAN setup, on the X1 Interface.  We have an A record setup with the same static IP used on the WAN Interface, and is configured for mail.company.com.

Should I use a new static IP from our block of usable IP's to create the new Remote.Company.com? If so, I have no idea where to start on this on the Sonicwall?

Any suggestions?

Comment: I might be on the wrong track, but when I try to configure a new interface, like X2, I try to duplicate X1, with the only change being the new Static IP that I've configured for Remote.OurCompany.com.  I then get the error below.


: Error: Index of the interface.: Subnet on this interface overlaps with another interface

Answer (score 1):

The only reason I would think you would need a 2nd WAN interface for this would be if you were running the SSLVPN on a separate ISP.

If the ports were already in use on that existing IP address (which might be the case for your 443 port for OWA, but maybe not) then you can still add a 2nd IP to the existing interface and give it an A record.

I would recommend creating a new A record and using a separate IP for your SSLVPN.

2 Reasons why:

1. You can easily monitor traffic by destination IP
2. You can create your A record for this IP and make it easier for users to remember (something like vpn.company.com)

There are KB articles for Sonicwall for adding a 2nd IP to an existing interface.  I'm pretty sure you can use the wizards in the GUI as well.  See here for a similar question here on SF: [Sonicwall NSA 240 Multiple WAN IP Addresses](https://serverfault.com/questions/455472/sonicwall-nsa-240-multiple-wan-ip-addresses) to help you out.